# How to add <br/> tag dynamically in <p> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written html as below lines of code.

```
<div class="da-slide">
    <h2><i><asp:Label ID="lblHeading3" runat="server"></asp:Label></i></h2>
    <p>
       <i><asp:Label ID="lblDescription3" runat="server"></asp:Label> </i>
    </p>
    <div class="da-img">
       <img src="../img/bg/html5andcss3.png" alt="image01" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to add br tag inside p tag after every four words dynamically.
Please help me!!!

Comment: How are you getting the input for <p>?

Comment: What do you mean `after every four words`?

Answer (score 1):

Relying on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16906541/4202224) on how to get all the words of a specific text-node you can try the following:

```
var res = $('.da-slide p *').contents().map(function () {
    if (this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.trim() != "") //check for nodetype text and ignore empty text nodes
    return this.nodeValue.trim().split(/\W+/); //split the nodevalue to get words.
}).get(); //get the array of words.

var new_content = [];
$.each(res, function(index, value){
    index++; // avoid the modulo operation with index 0
    if(index % 4 === 0){
        new_content.push(value + '<br/>'); //add a break after every 4th word
    }else{
        new_content.push(value);
    }
    console.log(new_string);

});

$('.da-slide p i').html(new_content.join(' ')); //concatenate the new content with whitespaces
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oh9b0n6e/)**

---

**Reference**

[.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

[.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)

[.get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

[.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

[Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)

Comment: Sorry!!! its not appending <br/> after 4th word inside p tag.... please help me !!!

Comment: @Nida The demo just works fine, can you post an example of the content you getting inside your `p`-tag ?

Comment: <p>
                   <i><span id="ctl00_SliderContent_lblDescription1">jhjgju jguytuytu uyguugu uguytut iuiyiuyi uigigbvh</span> </i>
                </p>

Comment: Try it with the `$('.da-slide p *')` in the first function. See my updated answer.

Comment: It still isn't working.... do i have to call some jquery libraby files other than jquery min

Comment: @Nida The jQuery is enough. Did you get any erros in the console?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the best approach; however you could achieve this using `split`, `mod` and `join`

```
// find all <p> elements in the 'da-slide' using jQuery and loop through each instance
$('p', '.da-slide').each(function(p_i, p_el){

    // get the text for this <p> element
    var txt = $(p_el).text();

    // split the text into individual words (assume separated by space)
    var txt_split = txt.split(' ');

    // every 4th word place a <br>
    var txt_tokenized = [];
    txt_split.forEach(function(string, index){
        if (parseInt(index) % 4 == 0){
            txt_tokenized.push('<br/>');
        }
        txt_tokenized.push(string);
    });

    // rebuild as html    
    $(p_el).html(txt_tokenized.join(' '));
});
```